# unable to open the div on hover and select the content inside div as well

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

i'm working on a menu inside a div and this menu open on hovering over an image and text but unable to do so. i have written visibility hidden and its not working but when i gave it display none its working but not selecting anything. how can i achieve it.

i want something like this site's menu:
http://www.luxado.in/index.php/customer/account/add/

here is my css:

```
ul.sec-menu{float: right;list-style: none outside none;margin-right: 36px;margin-top: 34px;width: auto;}
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}ul.sec-menu li:last-child{border-right: medium none;}
ul.sec-menu li{float: right;font-family: 'Merriweather Sans',sans-serif;width: auto;}
li{list-style: none outside none;}
ul.sec-menu li a{color: #FFFFFF;float: left;font-family: 'Merriweather Sans',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;padding: 0 25px 20px 0;text-align: center;text-decoration: none; width: auto;}
.account{background: url("http://projects.flashonmind.com/hoppworldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/exploreIcon.png") no-repeat scroll 101% 1% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);height: 18px;/*margin: 0 -11px 0 -10px !important;*/margin: 0 -50px 0 -10px !important;}
.for-current-sale-account{/*background: url("http://projects.flashonmind.com/hoppworldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/menuBg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);*/background-color:#000000;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;float: left;height: auto;margin-right: 25px;padding: 10px 13px;position: absolute;right: 0;/*top: 69px;*/top: 100px;visibility: hidden;width: 191px;z-index: 300;}
.up-arrow4{background: url("http://projects.flashonmind.com/hoppworldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/toolTip.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);float: left;height: 18px;opacity: 0.55;position: absolute;/*top: -18px;*/top: -11px;width: 184px;}*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.for-current-sale-account ul{float: left;list-style: none outside none;margin-bottom: 0;padding: 10px;width: 183px;}
.for-current-sale-account ul li{border: medium none;color: #FFFFFF;float: left;line-height: 29px;list-style: none outside none;width: 92%;}
ul.sec-menu li{/*float: right;*/font-family: 'Merriweather Sans',sans-serif;/*width: auto;*/}
ul.sec-menu li:hover{visibility:visible;display:inline-block;}
img_menu{border: medium none;}
```

Here is my div with menu content:

```
<ul class="sec-menu">
    <li><a class="account" href="#">EXPLORE</a>
        <div id="my-account" class="for-current-sale-account" style="height:auto;">
        <div class="up-arrow4">&nbsp;</div>
            <ul class="part-one">
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">Exclusive Indulgences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">Experiences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">Honeymoon </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">Private Villas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">Media & Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page1 all-click about-us">Newsletters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="page2 all-click contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="page3 all-click">Magazine</a></li> -->
            </ul>
            <script src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
               <!--script for google+ sharing end-->
            <ul class="social-networks">
                    <li style="padding-left:10px;"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Luxado"><img class="fb-hover" src="http://luxado.in/skin/frontend/default/hotel/images/facebook.png"  /></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/Luxadotravel"><img class="twi-hover" src="http://luxado.in/skin/frontend/default/hotel/images/twitter.png"  /></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/103241305149258811392/posts"><img class="g-hover" src="http://luxado.in/skin/frontend/default/hotel/images/gplus.png"  /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Jquery :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sec-menu").mouseover(function(e) {
       $("#my-account").css("display","block");
    });
     $("#my-account").mouseout(function(e) {
       $("#my-account").css("display","none");
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: can u create a fiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use display: none instead of visibility in .for-current-sale-account class. See following.

```
.for-current-sale-account {
    /*background: url("http://projects.flashonmind.com/hoppworldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/menuBg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    /*top: 69px;*/
    top: 100px;
    display: none;
    width: 191px;
    z-index: 300;
}
```

Also check out this working jsfiddle...[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxWrb/1/)

Comment: @ Nikhil:thanks dear that working like a charm..:) i just have one problem that in chrome its not working properly means there is a big gap between the menu and link.

Comment: You need to do little bit changes in your css related to position..around up arrow and dropdown menu..:)

Comment: thanks bro will do it for sure. if u got something please let me know..thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".sec-menu").mouseover(function(e) {
       $("#my-account").css("display","block");
    });
   $(".sec-menu").mouseout(function(e) {
       $("#my-account").css("display","none");
   });
});
```

css:

```
#my-account {
   display: none;
}
```

see example on jsFiddle:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsZFR/8/)

Comment: @ Dvir :thanks dear that working..:) i just have one problem that in chrome its not working properly means there is a big gap between the menu and link.

Comment: Try to add this to the css:
`.for-current-sale-account { top: 70px !important; }`

Comment: thanks dear i have done this its working great in chrome but now in mozilla its not working...:(